# Use Powershell to Save Email Attachments from Inbox from a Second Email Account

Tags: powershell, outlook, email-attachments

I have written a script that will cycle through my outlook inbox and save a specific file attachment that I receive daily.

I have two email addresses that I use with Outlook.  Example:  jdoe@company1.com and jdoe@company2.com

The problem I have run into is that my script will only go through and save the attachments from the Inbox of my first (default) email account (jdoe@company1.com), but I need the script to save the attachments from my other inbox belonging to (jdoe@company2.com).

I am a novice with PowerShell and I've not been able to find a solution online.  I am using PowerShell 5.1 and below is my script.

```
$td = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"

$AttachFile = "File Name.xlsx"
$FileSavePath = "C:\Temp\Attached_File_" + $td + ".xlsx"

$outlook = new-object -com outlook.application

$mapi = $outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$inbox = $mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6)

$emails = $inbox.Items

foreach ($email in $emails) {
    if ($email.ReceivedTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") = $td) {
    
    $email.Attachments | Where-Object {$_.FileName -eq $AttachFile} | foreach {
        $_.SaveAsFile($FileSavePath)
    }}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `Namespace.GetDefaultFolder` (which only returns folders from your default store), use `Namespace.Stores` collection, find the store you want (`mapi.Stores.Item("jdoe@company2.com")` ?), and use `Store.GetDefaultFolder`.

Also, do not loop through all items in a folder - use `Items.Restrict` or `Items.Find/FindNext` with a query like `"([ReceivedTime] < '11-15-2023') and ([ReceivedTime] > '11-14-2023')"`